# Avoid Background Image From Stretching

Tags: css, background-image

I put `background-image` on my site but the result image is stretched.
How I can avoid it?

CSS:

```
background: rgb(236, 242, 196) url(../images/border.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
margin-left: auto;
background: rgb(236, 242, 196);
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 75px;
```

How I can avoid stretched image `width` and `height` and make it auto `width` and `height`.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what happens.

Comment: The stretch is due to background-size: 100% 100%;, you can use background-size : cover(to fill horizontally) or contain(to fill vertically).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem, you should use:

```
 background-size: cover;
```